# solcjs --standard-json is not working

Tags: solidity, solcjs

I was trying to compile a .sol file using **solcjs --standardjson inputConfig.json** command, the compilation had thrown error. But when I try with Solidity compiler, the compilation was success.

Can you please instruct me how to compile with **solcjs --standardjson** command?

***My inputConfig.json content is:***

```
{"language": "Solidity",
"sources":
{
   "testEth.sol":
{
"urls":[
    "E:\Solidity\testEth\testEth\testEth.sol"
     ]
  }
},
"settings":
{
   "optimizer": {
      "enabled": true
},
    "evmVersion": "byzantium",
    "outputSelection": {
     "*": {
       "*": [
           "abi", "evm.bytecode"
          ]
       }
     }
  }
}
```

Following texts are the error message had thrown:

**fs.js:193
let mode = stats[1];
^

TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
at isFileType (fs.js:193:19)
at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:380:16)
at Object. (C:\Users\john\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\solc\solcjs:60:18)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47**

Answer (score 0):

I have pretty much the same problem, and have raised it as an [issue](https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js/issues/601) on the GitHub repository of solc-js.

If your main goal is to deploy the contract on Ethereum and play around with it, then as a temporary alternative, you can instead compile your contract using the `--abi` and `--bin` options, because that's all you really need in order to deploy and interact with the contract.